# Count how many Yes and No in column, grouped by another column

Tags: google-sheets

My goal is to create a query that shows how many yes's and how many no's per class there are.

Example data

- Class    | Regular Usage
- senior   |   y
- senior   |   y
- softmore |   n
- freshmen |   y
- softmore |   y
- junior   |   n
- junior   |   n

So fare I can get how many yes's there are using the below query

```
=query(Sheet1!1:100000, "Select A, count(C) where C = 'y' group by (A) label count(C) 'Yes'",1)
```

However I would like to include a third column, that shows the No counts for each class.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try pivot in your query:

```
=query(Sheet1!1:1000; "Select A, count(B) where A <>'' group by (A) pivot C";1)
```